# printf, sprintf print at least two decimal places

Tags: formatting, printf

I'm trying to figure out how to use sprintf to print at least two decimal places and no leading zeros.  For instance

input:

```
23
23.0
23.5
23.55
23.555
23.0000
```

output:

```
23.00
23.00
23.50
23.55
23.555
23.00
```

any formatting help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your programming language, otherwise people will become crazy in replying and moderating this also in 2023 :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no such built-in format specifier. You could check if the number to be printed has two or fewer decimals (round to two decimals and compare), and if so use %.02f. If the number has more decimals, use a %g specifier. Here's an example in Ruby:

```
def print_two_dec(number)
  rounded = (number*100).to_i / 100.0
  if number == rounded
    printf "%.02f\n", number
  else
    printf "%g\n", number
  end
end

[ 23, 23.0, 23.5, 23.55, 23.555 ].each do |number|
  print_two_dec(number)
end
```

Outputs:

```
23.00
23.00
23.50
23.55
23.555
```

Comment: BTW, given that float values often have slight rounding errors, instead of comparing the original value to the rounded value, also round the original value to the maximum number of digits you ever want to display. So if you will limit to "5", then do `if (round(value, 5) == round(value, 2))` then display with two.

Answer (score 3):

in PHP you could use

```
<?php
$number = 0.56;
echo sprintf("%0.2f",$number);
```

Comment: Nope. He said *at least* 2 decimal places. Just tested this, it will truncate in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you may use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function for this purpose, too, which also allows you to change delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

In php this is what I did (inspired by this post).  Maybe not the most elegant but...  I made a function for printing numbers as strings.  I wanted to be able to have flexibility so I have a couple of parameters.

PHP:

```
function print_num($num,$numdec,$atleast = false,$max_dec = -1)
{

  $ret_norm = false;

  if (!$atleast)
    $ret_norm = true;
  else //atleast = true
  {
    //Want at least $numdec decimals

    //Do we have two or fewer and want to return two or fewer?
    if ($num == ((int)($num*100)/100) & $numdec <= 2 )
      $ret_norm = true;
    else
    {
      //See if we have enough dec. already
      $just_dec = substr((string)$num,strpos((string)$num,".") + 1);
      if ($numdec >= strlen($just_dec))
        $ret_norm = true;
      else
      {
        //More decimals than at least value - make sure we don't go over max if set
        if ( $max_dec >= 0 && strlen($just_dec) > $max_dec )
        {
          //Confine to max_dec length
          $ret_norm = true;
          $numdec = $max_dec;                   //Set for sprintf below
          $num = number_format($num,$max_dec);  //Round the value so doesn't just chop off

        }
        else if ($max_dec >= 0)
          $ret_norm = false;
      } //else
    } //else
  } //else atlest

  if ($ret_norm)
    return sprintf("%0.".$numdec."f",$num);
  else
      return sprintf("%s",$num); //print as is

} //print_num
```

And to call the function (to have at least two decimals but max 4:

```
print_num($mynum,2,true,4);
```

If the number is 34.1, you get 34.10

If the number is 34.12345 you get 34.1235

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does "23.555".toFixed(2) not do what I think it does? (Javascript)

Comment: The topic is about formatting. Not rounding. Besides, `toFixed` has a reputation for being wildly inconsistent as to whether it rounds up or down.

Comment: The difference between formatting and rounding seems semantic when the question is about formatting value to a certain number of decimal places. If you have some specifics about the inconsistency of `toFixed` that might be a helpful addition.

Answer (score 0):

just had that problem and the solution is: just add zero!

```
v=sprintf("%.2f",v) + 0;
print(v);
```

The "+ 0" forces a math operation that removes trailing zeros. For PERL, I used:

```
$v=sprintf("%.2f",$v) + 0;
print($v);
```

but for other languages, you may need to add a cast of stringToFloat.